# Variable 'Foo' used before declaration. Two classes interdependence

Tags: angularjs, typescript, tslint

Please, help me solve the problem.

`"no-use-before-declare"` in `tslint.json` is `true`. And I am not allowed to change it.

The problem is following - "variable 'foo' used before declaration" build error.

The code may be simplified to:

```
export class One {
    toSecond() : Two {
        return new Two();
    }
}

export class Two {
    toFirst() : One {
        return new One();
    }
}
```

Could it be hacked somehow to overcome the linter warning and have the same result. Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
let Two_forward: typeofTwo;

export class One {
    toSecond() : Two {
        return new Two_forward();
    }
}

export class Two {
    toFirst() : One {
        return new One();
    }
}
// Work around https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3655
type typeofTwo = typeof Two;
Two_forward = Two;
```

but IMO this is unreasonable compared to just suppressing the lint error with `// tslint:disable-next-line:no-use-before-declare`.  (And it might need further changes if the `strictLocalInitialization` option proposed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23305) becomes part of `strict`.)

Comment: Thank you very much @Matt, TSLint rule flags is the best solution for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This was previously filed as a [bug on tslint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3011) and the resolution was that classes are not hoisted and cannot be used before declaration. The rule is correct in this case.